# How can I sort a datatable using an outside list (prefer linq)?

Tags: vb.net, linq, sorting, datagridview, datatable

I have an unsorted datatable with several rows.  One of my datatable columns is a unique Integer ID.

I have a separate method outside of my datatable that is processing information from this table (with some other data) and returning me a sorted list of the IDs in my table.

What I want to do is represent my datatable in a datagridview, sorted using the list that was returned to me from my method.  The sorted list is a List(Of Integer) that contains all of the IDs from my table.

Comment: What is the significance of the list? Do you just want to sort your data by id and show this on the grid?

Comment: What about any IDs not in the list?

Comment: The IDs in the list are guaranteed to be in the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = result
    .Where(l => ids.Any(id => id == l.id))
    .ToList()
    .OrderBy(l => ids.IndexOf(l.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add a "Sort" column on your datatable:

```
myDataTable.Columns.Add("SortCol", typeof(Int32));
for (int i=0;i<MyDataTable.Rows.Count;i++) 
  myDataTable.Rows[i]["SortCol"]=mySortedList.IndexOf(myDataTable.Rows[i]["Id"] ;
```

Then, use a bindingSource to bind the DataTable to the DataGridView:

```
BindingSource myBindingSource = new BindingSource() ;
myGridView.BindingSource      = myBindingSource ;
myBindingSource.DataSource    = myDataTable ;
```

Finally, Hide the "SortCol" and Sort the datagridView:

```
myGridView.Columns["SortCol"].Visible = false ;
myBindingSource.Sort = "SortCol ASC" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that in a `Join` the order of the first collection is preserved:

```
Dim ids = { 4, 2, 3, 1 }
Dim dt = new DataTable()

dt.Columns.Add("ID", GetType( integer))

dt.Rows.Add( { 1 })
dt.Rows.Add( { 2 })
dt.Rows.Add( { 3 })
dt.Rows.Add( { 4 })

Dim query = From id In ids
            Join row in dt.AsEnumerable On id Equals row(0)
            Select row
```

`query` will now return the data rows as `4, 2, 3, 1`.

You can use [`CopyToDataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert the results back to a Datatable.

Comment: Thanks.  I used something very similar to this.

Comment: Yes, I see. That's an almost exact copy of my answer. Not that I'm in any way suggesting that you actually copied it (we just come to the same conclusion independently), but repeating it isn't very useful either. The Stack-Overflow way would be to mark an answer as accepted. You're  even allowed edit it! (Like changing it into `Field(Of Integer)("ID")`). The moment I post it, it's not 'mine' any more.

Comment: thanks sorry - i am new to the stackoverflow thing.  usually just lurked for ideas.  decided to start asking and answering

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I used: (note that keyList is the List(Of Integer) of IDs in my table that have been sorted)

```
Dim sortQuery = From id In keyList
                Join row In myTable.AsEnumerable On id Equals row.Field(Of Integer)("ID")
                Select row

Dim newtable = sortQuery.CopyToDataTable
```